# pyqt "ItemIgnoresParentOpacity" Flag being ignored

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem

I've taken the time to do a Minimal Reproducible Example of my issue.

Using PyQt5, I have a classic Main window, with a QGraphicsView linked to a QGraphicsScene.

On the scene, I have a `NodeHover` item (green circle) with a `TreeNode` child (square).
The NodeHover item is transparent by default, and becomes opaque when hovered.

[image]

I want **its child item (`TreeNode`) to remain opaque all the time**, no matter the parent's opacity. I've tried setting flags in both items, as you can see below, but they seem not to work.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow, QApplication, QToolBar, QStatusBar, QAction, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsLineItem, QLabel, QGraphicsEllipseItem, QGraphicsTextItem

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QIcon, QPen, QBrush, QTransform


class NodeHover(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NodeHover, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOpacity(0.1)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        # Setting the flag so Item doesn't propagate its opacity to children
        self.GraphicsItemFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemDoesntPropagateOpacityToChildren)

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        self.setOpacity(1) # When mouse enters item, make it opaque
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setOpacity(0.1) # When mouse leaves item, make it transparent

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0, 20, 20)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.green))
        painter.drawEllipse(QPointF(10, 10), 10, 10)

    
class TreeNode(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TreeNode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Setting the flag to ignore parent's opacity
        self.GraphicsItemFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresParentOpacity)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(100, 100, 100, 100)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        painter.drawRect(110,110,80,80)


class GView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 700, 450)
        self.show()


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        hoverItem = NodeHover() # create a NodeHover item
        self.addItem(hoverItem)
        nodeItem = TreeNode()   # create a TreeNode item and make it hoverItem's child
        nodeItem.setParentItem(hoverItem)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(900, 70, 1000, 800)
        self.createGraphicView()
        self.show()

    def createGraphicView(self):
        self.scene = Scene(self)
        gView = GView(self)
        scene = Scene(gView)
        gView.setScene(scene)
        # Set the main window's central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(gView)

# Run program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a flag to the QGraphicsItem you must use the [`setFlag()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setFlag) method:

```py
self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemDoesntPropagateOpacityToChildren)
```

```py
self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresParentOpacity)
```

**Note:** One of those flags is enough.

Comment: This works great, as well as your previous solution.
Thanks a lot for the help, I don't know how i missed the .setFlag() method in the documentation.